# How to identify whether an Excel file is created in excel version 8.0, 9.0,10.0 or 11.0?

Tags: excel, specifications

As per documentation http://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf, BIFF version is same for excel version 8.0 to 11.0.
I need to find out in which excel version the particular excel file is created.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please [show us your code.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just ran this exmaple http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/freexl-1.0.0e-doxy-doc/test_xl_8c-example.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way of knowing which Excel version originally created the file (I don't know of a reason why knowing would be required).

You can find out which Excel version last calculated the file (assuming it was calculated before being saved) using Workbook.CalculationVersion.